# Inverse Fourier transformation discrepancy between Wolfram|Alpha's solution and mine

Tags: fourier-analysis, inverse

I searched for the inverse fourier transformation of
$$ \mathcal{F(\omega)} = \frac{2}{(1+i\cdot \omega)^2 +4} \rightarrow i^2=-1 $$

My solution (compliant with the solution from my textbook): 
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{\omega\}\} = e^{-t}\cdot \sin{(2t)}\cdot \sigma {(t)}$$
[Wolfram|Alpha:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20fourier%20transform%202%2F((1%2Bi*%5Comega)%5E2%2B4))
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{\omega\}\} = i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{(1-2 i) t} \left(-1+e^{4 i t}\right) \theta (-t) $$
Where does this difference come from and how can I make the output equal to my solution?

Comment: If you want someone to explain you the mathematical equivalence and required assumptions, you should better ask it from [Mathematics.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FourierParameters-> {1, -1}`:

```
InverseFourierTransform[2/((1 + I ω)^2 + 4), ω, t, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] // FullSimplify
```

> $$e^{-t} \theta (t) \sin (2 t)$$

More info about `FourierParameters` [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourierTransform.html).